# Edit mode for textbox column in Telerik RadGridView for Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have developed a RadGridView in Winforms with two GridViewTextBoxColumn properties. The problem here is i am unable to edit the text in text box of RadGridView. When i click the cell, the program stops functioning. I have posted some code in the following.

Please suggest me a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
 Dim textboxColumn As GridViewTextBoxColumn
  textboxColumn = CType(Me.RadGridView1.Columns("Name"), GridViewTextBoxColumn)
            textboxColumn.HeaderText = "Name"
            textboxColumn.IsVisible = True
            textboxColumn.WrapText = True
            textboxColumn.Width = 100
            textboxColumn.MinWidth = 200
            textboxColumn.MaxWidth = 200
            textboxColumn.Multiline = True
            Me.RadGridView1.Columns.Move(textboxColumn.Index, 0)

            textboxColumn = CType(Me.RadGridView1.Columns("Description"), GridViewTextBoxColumn)
            textboxColumn.HeaderText = "Description"
            textboxColumn.IsVisible = True
            textboxColumn.WrapText = True
            textboxColumn.Width = 100
            textboxColumn.MinWidth = 200
            textboxColumn.MaxWidth = 200
            textboxColumn.Multiline = True
            Me.RadGridView1.Columns.Move(textboxColumn.Index, 1)
```

Comment: You get any exception?

Comment: No.I have not got any exception.

Comment: Show also your cell click event.

Comment: i have not written CellClick event.

Comment: @mww i have found out where i have gone wrong. i have used RadGridView1.AutoSize = True at the end of gridload function. so when i remove the RadGridView1.AutoSize = True it works fine